# Check all object values inside Array javascript has boolean false

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have below object inside array

```
    [
    {
        "age":32,
        "test":true
    },
    {
        "age":33,
        "test":true
    },
    {
        "age":35,
        "test":false
    }
]
```

I need to check if all values of `test` is `false`.

I have tried below code

```
Array.isArray(obj.map((message,index) => {
      if(message.test !== message.test){
          //trigger when all values are false
      }
}))
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `every` from Array prototype:

```
let areAllFalse = array.every(x => x.test === false);
```

Comment: Can be shortened to `array.every(x => !x.test)`

Comment: @bugs possibly can be but he explicitly mentioned to check against `false` not `undefined` and other falsy values

Answer (score 0):

You can also you filter from array prototype...

```
const filtered = array.filter(a => a.test === true)
```

or the less verbose

```
const filtered = array.filter(a => a.test)
```

Comment: if (filtered) {
...
}

Comment: So you just told me how you would tell if they were all false, you might want to add that to the answer as OP seems new and may not know that. Because right now you are showing how to filter an array without answering the question and helping OP learn.